# Css grid - html form - I fail to direct my element in a vertical flow

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I fail to create a vertical direction with my flexbox.

[Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rnrjnw8vm).

Despite I have create a grid specifically to direct them vertically. I can't figure out why it fails. 
I have tried with flexbox basis using direction property but it fail.

Here my react.js snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import style from "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    message: ""
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  sendForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(
      "form sent: ",
      this.state.name,
      this.state.email,
      this.state.message
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className={style.mailform_container} onSubmit={this.sendForm}>
          <div>
            <input
              className={style.mailform_name}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              name="name"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.name}
              placeholder="name"
            />
            <input
              className={style.mailform_email}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              name="email"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.email}
              placeholder="email"
            />
            <textarea
              className={style.mailform_message}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              name="message"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.message}
              placeholder="message"
            >
              Enter text here...
            </textarea>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" className={style.mailform_confirm}>
            Envoyer
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

Here my style.css snippet:

```
.mailform_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "name"
    "email"
    "message"
    "confirm";
}

.mailform_name {
  grid-area: name;
}

.mailform_email {
  grid-area: email;
}

.mailform_message {
  grid-area: message;
}

.mailform_confirm {
  grid-area: confirm;
}

.nmailform_confirm:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nmailform_confirm:active {
  background-color: rgb(200, 198, 196);
}
```

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: None of your styles are being applied to the elements in your demo, that and having the div wrapping all the elements is probably the source of your problem.

Comment: Read Stevens answer, that is what fixed it for me in your demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using grid, all elements you want to be placed by the grid need to be a direct child of the grid. In your case, you have a `<div>` element as the first child which wraps all the other form elements, so the form elements are not part of the grid. If you remove the `<div>`, your example will work.

Comment: This is the solution, I just tested it in his demo and it worked.